# SQL IF statement for unique rows

Tags: mysql, excel, if-statement

I am working in Excel and Im trying to make an if sql statement:

="INSERT INTO Roles (Role Type, Role, Trade) VALUES ("&A1&", '"&B1&"');"

In my C column I have a numbers in the first 13 rows and then I have string in rows 14 to 19. I am trying to make an If statement so that the first 13 rows are treated as a number and rows 14 to 19 are treated as a string. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may run into issues because often in sql schema you have to declare what type of object will go in that column so what you are trying to do may not work.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Treat them all as strings. The target field schema is more important than the source data.